# Is "compute" sometimes used as a noun, to mean "computational power"?

Tags: terminology, vocabulary, technology

I have seen compute being used in this way before, as in "We have much more compute today than in the 1960s." Is this commonly accepted? If so, is stress placed on the second syllable as in the verb form, or on the first?

Comment: It is slang/casual style.  Not valid in formal writing.

Comment: @HotLicks So its impute is ill repute? I used to use *crunch* this way (a long time ago).

Comment: The word should be "computation", I think.  It's been bugging me so that's how I got here.  Anyway, looks like it's a actually a thing, although informal (at least).

Answer (score 1):

From Wiktionary [compute](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/compute):

> #### Pronunciation
>
> - enPR: kəm-pyo͞ot', IPA: /kəmˈpjuːt/
>
> #### Verb
>
> **compute** (*third-person singular simple present* **computes**, *present participle* **computing**, *simple past and past participle* **computed**)
>
> 1. (*transitive*) To reckon or calculate.
>      *Can anyone here **compute** the square root of 10201?*
> 2. (*intransitive, informal*) To make sense.
>      *Does that **compute**, or do I need to explain further?*
>
> #### Noun
>
> **compute** (*uncountable*)
>
> 1. (*computing, informal*) computational power
>
>    - **2015**, J. Powell, *Mastering vRealize Automation 6.2* (page 41)
>        Once you have the total, does it exceed the maximum amount of **compute** that can be served up in your vCenter environment? It is quite normal for users to consume everything you provide.
>    - **2016**, Joe Baron, ‎Hisham Baz, ‎Tim Bixler, *AWS Certified Solutions Architect Official Study Guide: Associate Exam*
>        To change the amount of **compute** and memory, you can select a different DB Instance class of the database.

Wiktionary gives the pronunciation (it doesn't differ between the verb and the noun), and also mentions that its use as a noun is informal.